# Как перезагрузить модальное окно не закрывая его

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Хочу решить такую проблему, у меня на сайте есть модальное окно, которое открывается при нажатии на определенный товар в строке таблицы. В модальном окне я редактирую данные через ajax без перезагрузки, помимо текстовых данных я загружаю изображения для товара. Чтобы изображения отобразились для пользователя у меня идет перезагрузка страницы через **php**

```
header("Location: /pr1.php");
```

С одной стороны, да этот метод работает. Данные успешно добавлены и пользователь видит что он сделал, но с другой стороны у меня выходит минус для пользователя, как только модальное окно закрывается, страница перезагружается и всё. Получается пользователь теряет свое модальное окно в котором он работал. Подскажите как сделать так чтобы, фотографии добавлялись в модальное окно с перезагрузкой страницы но при этом само модальное окно не закрывалось. То есть грубо говоря страница с модальным окно остается и модальное окно не закрывается.
При нажатии на кнопку (Удалить страница будет перезагружена и модальное окно закрыто. ) С одной стороны пробовал на ajax сделать, что если например картинки удалены то выводилось сообщение в модальном окне, что действие было выполнено без перезагрузки.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".prosm").on("click", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id"); //получаем id текущей кнопки
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("/module/winmodal.php", {
            id: id
        }, function(result) { //передача id
            $("#modal-content1").html(result); //записываем полученые с обработчика данные с запроса в диалоговое окно
            $("#myModal").modal('show'); //открытие модального окна
        });
    });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: модальное окно на *bootstrap*

Answer (score 1):

Перечислю самые простые на мой взгляд варианты.

**Первый вариант**: это отказаться от таблицы которая имеется у вас сейчас написать скрипт на js который будет строить вашу таблицу а после измененний данных у таблицы должна быть возможность перестроиться.
Конечно можно взять готовые таблицы подобного типа такие как [Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/),[Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)[jqGrid](http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/demos/jqgrid-standalone/preserve-selection-horizontal-scroll-on-sort). Все они имеют нужный вам функционал и просты в использовании. Но посоветовал бы конечно попробовать самому написать для  изучения  просто.

**Второй вариант:** Передавать с индификатор редактируемого товара и после обработки с помощью того же AJAX изменять конкретную строку в таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема в отображении картинки, то после отправки запроса на загрузку изображения(с помощью AJAX), отправляйте ответ с адресом до уже загруженного изображения, получив ответ уже можно обновить адрес изображения без перезагрузки страницы.